# Using ImageMagick or other libraries in AWS Lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, imagemagick, aws-lambda

I'm new in AWS world, and now I'm trying to create a lambda function to process some images storage in a bucket.

The issue that I have is that I don't know how to include ImageMagick library in the AWS Lambda project in order to count with the library for my app...

I also need to use tesseract, but I can image that the solution is the same for both.

Answer (score -1):

Lambda sounds like the wrong service for what you are trying to do. You can't install libraries in a lambda function, you can only bundle the code dependencies that are used to run the function.

If you require ImageMagick or tesseract then consider using another service such as ECS that gives you full control over what is installed.

If you are processing images as they arrive to the bucket then you can use a lambda to run an ECS task.

Comment: You can possibly use ImageMagick in AWS. Magick.NET (C# version of that library in .NET) can be used in AWS lambda. See: https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/issues/150#issuecomment-371973573. Should also be possible in java.

Comment: You most certainly can use ImageMagick (version 6) in Lambda as it is available by default.